# Select only selected object and all its children

Tags: parent

I select an object (parent) in 3d view. How can i setup the outliner to show only the selected object and all its children ?

The only way i can do is by setting the filter to 'selected' and turn off 'collection' . But it will only show the single parent. So then i have to select its children (shift G) .

Is it possible just to select the parent only and show its entire tree /hierarchy ?

Comment: Good question, I would like to know the same. To get around this I just keep really organized collections that I can turn on/off when I need to isolate linked geometry.